# How to decompress .tar.gz zip files in azure data factory v2

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image][[image: enter image description here][1]]I have a .tar.gz compressed folder in SFTP. I would like to decompress into folders using azure data factory. Could you help me with it?

ErrorCode-AdlsGen20perationFailed, 'Type-Microsoft.DataTransfer. Common. Shared. HybridDeliveryException, Message-ADLS Gen2 operation failed
for: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'. Account : 'stIhgpe lesourcenonp'. Filesystem: "agam". ath:
'agam/ cobra2 /PELE PROD 20230401/home/corona/pele/to azure/agam backup// PELE PROD 20230401/agam/ FRA-AGP/DIRECTION = AGP-FRA/ POC = DE/DDAY
= Friday/COMP = Economy/BCC = N/agam prod 20230401/BDAF/BDAF. RDS'. Message: 'The request URI is invalid. ". RequestId:
"04a46d29-601f-0059-326c-7e4f9e000000*
TimeStamp: Thu, 04 May 2023 09:43: 43
GMT'
Source-Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary, ' "Type-Microsoft.DataTransfer. Common. Shared.HybridDeliveryException, Message-The file
name agam/cobra2/PELE PROD 20230401/home/corona/pele/to azure/agam backup//PELE PROD 20230401/agam/ FRA-AGP/DIRECTION AGP-FRA/ POC =
DE/DDAY = Friday/COMP = Economy/BCC = N/agam prod 20230401/BDAF/BDAF. RDS does not conform to the naming rules by the data store 'Azure
Data Lake Storage Gen2'., Source=, ""Type-Microsoft.Azure.Storage. Data.Models. ErrorSchemaException, Message-Operation returned an invalid
status code 'BadRequest',Source-Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To decompress `.tar.gz` zip files in azure data factory v2 there is in built option as **Compression type** there you need to select **tar.gz** and it will decompress the folder.

[image]

**Output:**

***decompressed the folder and copped all files in destination***

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot pratik but we are having sub folders inside it.. So i am getting an error

Comment: I have attached error screenshot

Comment: I also tried with sub folder in it, and it is working fine, please share the setting and connection of your dataset and don't put error msg in image format add it as text format.

Comment: I have added dataset config and error details

Comment: Zip folder has multiple sub folders, after decompress it should extract sub folders as is and they will have individual files in it.

Comment: The error code is mainly saying that its naming convention is not correct can you please check path and file naming once.